# Annotation lines for iphone videos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am working on an iPhone application where i be creating an video where i can annotate the video with lines . 
I have gone through the library but could not find anything that could help me till now .

I would really appreciate it if anyone could show some light on this matter at the earliest.

Thanking You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add yourown graphics or text or lines to the video have a look at AVFoundation, should be able to do what you wAnt